# How to populate jQuery UI Select2 with Restangular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, jquery-select2

I can't see why Restangular would behave differently inside a jquery-ui callback to the way it does anywhere else. Can you?

The following works in my controller:

```
Restangular.all('skills').getList().then(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

However, when I use Restangular inside the query function for a jquery-ui-select2 (via angular-select2), it never makes a request.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ui-select2="skillOptions" ng-model="skills">
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.skillOptions = {
  multiple: true,
  query: function(query) {
    // I see this:
    console.log("Q:", query.term);
    // this silently fails:
    Restangular.all('skills').getList({
      query: query.term
    }).then(function(body) {
      // this callback is never reached (nor is the error one)
      var skills = body.skills;
      console.log("got skills", skills);
      query.callback({
        data: {
          text: 'name',
          results: skills
        }
      });
    }, function(error) {
      console.error("Error getting skills", error);
    });
  }
};
```

Is there another way to use the query callback with Restangular or can anybody see why on Earth this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to nest the callback in a `$scope.$apply` (since I am on AngularJS version 1.1.5) as per [this bit of the documentation](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#supported-angular-versions)

Here's some working code:

```
$scope.skillOptions = {
  multiple: true,
  query: function(query) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      Restangular.all('skills').getList({
        query: query.term
      }).then(function(body) {
        var skills;
        skills = body.skills;
        console.log("got skills", skills);
        return query.callback({
          results: _(skills).map(function(s) {
            return {
              text: s.name,
              id: s.id
            };
          })
        });
      }, function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting skills", error);
      });
    });
  }
};
```